# Finding which shared library has a symbol missing

Tags: c++

I have a c++ library which depends on a large group of shared libraries , when I try to load my library it shows a symbol is missing or not defined.
symbol missing is _ZrsIcERN7toolbox12UnmarshallerES2_RSt6vectorIT_SaIS4_EE
Now I did a nm -g on my lib to find if the symbol is missing in my lib or is it coming from a shared lib and I found that it is coming from a shared lib:- 
U _ZrsIcERN7toolbox12UnmarshallerES2_RSt6vectorIT_SaIS4_EE

I want to find the shared lib which my lib is trying to load and which has this symbol missing ?Can someone please help me to find this shared lib ?

Comment: Google the missing symbol?

Comment: No you did not get the question : I want to find the shared lib in which this symbol is missing? I know we can do a c++filt but which shared lib exactly has this symbol missing ?It is not in my lib but in a shared lib I need to find that shared lib which has this symbol as missing

Comment: generally this kind of error is when you have .so and headers of differet versions.

Comment: yes the lib is a xyz.so and it depends on other shared libs which are .so as well , I am not able to pinpoint the shared lib which has this missing symbol.It is for sure coming from an external shared lib

Comment: yes I tried ldd but it does not seem to resolve my issue.What my issue is that i have a lib A which depends on B which in turn depends on C.
A->B->C , and ldd shows symbol is missing in C . but what about B ? how should I check the hierarchy from which this issue is happening ?